# SQL query and SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i would like to select some datas from multiple tables, but i can see my limitations in SQL. Here is the return of MySQL with my query:

```
|idCandidate|   Date   |  Hour  |  NameOfTeacher  |
      758   |04/30/2015|  15h00 |    BRYAN
      856   |04/30/2015|  17h20 |    BRYAN
       20   |04/03/2015|  15h30 |    BRYAN
      956   |05/01/2015| 11h00  |    CARL
      758   |05/01/2015|  10h20 |    CARL
```

But i would like only the last niche of the day of each Teacher:
For BRYAN 17h20, for CARL 11h00

I think i can make it whith a select ... FROM... WHERE IN(....) but is there a more "beautiful" way?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your query ?

Comment: are your hours stored into a `DateTime` field ? That would be the first condition for a cleaner query

Comment: Note that dates adhere to a specific format in SQL.

Comment: Actually Date and Hours are in mysql format in the db

Answer (score 2):

Use a correlated sub-query to get each day/techer's latest lesson:

```
select idCandidate, Date, Hour, NameOfTeacher
from tablename t1
where hour = (select max(hour) from tablename t2
              where t1.date = t2.date
                and t1.NameOfTeacher = t2.NameOfTeacher)
```

Comment: Do you mean with an explicit join?

Comment: What about Javaluca's answer? Better or worse or same?

Comment: Suck it and see - but in my experience, an uncorrelated subquery generally performs faster than all other options.

Comment: Just done some basic tests, and Javaluca's solution is faster! Thank you two very much!

Comment: if t1 (and t2) is actually some tables with jointures, it works?

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's the same or different tables.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 'a'
                    FROM table t2
                    WHERE t2.date = t.date
                    AND t2.nameOfTeacher = t.NameOfTeacher
                    AND t2.hour > t.hour
                  )
```

This query return only the last row of each teacher and day